# How to get to Recovery mode?

Tags: boot

my Ubuntu shares the PC with windows 7 how would I get in to recovery mode for Ubuntu and my password is working for root ice tried reinstalling it but nothing any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can get to some recovery options by selecting Advanced Options for Ubuntu in the GRUB menu.

Just reboot your computer, and when you get to the GRUB menu, select the Advanced Options for Ubuntu using your arrow keys. You should see one option for recovery mode.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** As the OP is asking "How", could you [edit] and expand your answer a bit on which keys to press and which options to take?  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

If your grub menu does not pop automatically like it might for that user reboot your machine and as soon as it comes back on repeatedly press your left shift key till you get the page that says advanced options. From there it will take you to a page that has your version of Linux and then underneath that it will have the same thing just with (recovery) at the end of it.